# Problem when linking out to separate file within foreach loop

Tags: templates, php

I'm customizing my theme's category template to display the current category's child categories instead of the posts from that category.

The category template links to another template file (`content-grid.php`) which generates the dynamic post/category content.

The only way I can get it to work is by combining all the code together on the category template.

This is the original category template:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying category archive pages.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Codilight_Lite
 */

get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="site-content container <?php echo codilight_lite_sidebar_position(); ?>">
        <div class="content-inside">
            <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

                <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) : $count = 0; ?>

                    <header class="page-header">
                        <?php
                            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                            the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                        ?>
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->

                    <?php
                    $layout_archive_posts = get_theme_mod( 'layout_archive_posts', 'grid' );
                    if ( $layout_archive_posts == 'grid' ) {
                        echo '<div class="block1 block1_grid">';
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            $count++;
                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-grid' );
                            if ( $count % 2 == 0 ) {
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="row">';
                            }
                            endwhile;
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        codilight_lite_custom_paginate();

                    } else {
                        echo '<div class="block1 block1_list">';
                            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-list' );
                            endwhile;
                        codilight_lite_custom_paginate();
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </main><!-- #main -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

...and this is the `content-grid.php` template file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts with grid style.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Codilight_Lite
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'col-md-6 col-sm-12' ); ?>>
    <div class="entry-thumb">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) {
                the_post_thumbnail( 'codilight_lite_block_2_medium' );
            } else {
                echo '<img alt="'. esc_html( get_the_title() ) .'" src="'. esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/blank325_170.png' ) .'">';
            }
            ?>
        </a>
        <?php
        $category = get_the_category();
        if($category[0]){
            echo '<a class="entry-category" href="'.get_category_link($category[0]->term_id ).'">'.$category[0]->cat_name.'</a>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="entry-detail">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
            <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) codilight_lite_meta_1();?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-excerpt">
            <?php echo codilight_lite_excerpt(120); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

...and now for the customized category template file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Category Template: Custom
 */

get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="site-content container <?php echo codilight_lite_sidebar_position(); ?>">
        <div class="content-inside">
            <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
<?php 
        $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
        $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
        $child_categories=get_categories(
        array( 
        'parent' => $cat_id,
        // Uncomment the below line if you want empty category to appear on the list. 
        // 'hide_empty'   => 0
    )
); 
        if (!empty($child_categories)) : $count = 0; ?>

                    <header class="page-header">
                        <?php
                            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                            the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                        ?>
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->

                    <?php
                        echo '<div class="block1 block1_grid">';
                        echo '<div class="row">';

                    foreach ( $child_categories as $child ){ $count++;
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-grid' );

                    if ( $count % 2 == 0 ) {
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="row">';
                    }
                    }
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </main><!-- #main -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

...and the customized `content-grid.php` template file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts with grid style.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Codilight_Lite
 */

?>

<article id="" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">

    <div class="entry-thumb">

        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $child->cat_ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $child ->cat_name;?>">

    <?php $image_url = z_taxonomy_image_url($child->term_id); ?>

        <?php if (!empty($image_url)) : ?>
            <img alt="" src="<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url($child->term_id);?>" />

        <?php else: ?>
            <img alt="" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/blank325_170.png' ) ?>" />

    <?php endif; ?>

        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="entry-detail">

        <header class="entry-header">

            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $child->cat_ID ); ?> " rel="bookmark"><?php echo $child ->cat_name;?></a>
            </h2>

        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-excerpt">

            <?php echo $child ->description;?>

        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    </div>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

...and lastly this is how I put all the code together in the category template file which works:

```
<?php
/**
 * Category Template: Custom
 */

get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="site-content container <?php echo codilight_lite_sidebar_position(); ?>">
        <div class="content-inside">
            <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
<?php 
        $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
        $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
        $child_categories=get_categories(
        array( 
        'parent' => $cat_id,
        // Uncomment the below line if you want empty category to appear on the list. 
        // 'hide_empty'   => 0
    )
); 
        if (!empty($child_categories)) : $count = 0; ?>

                    <header class="page-header">
                        <?php
                            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                            the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                        ?>
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->

                    <?php
                        echo '<div class="block1 block1_grid">';
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                    foreach ( $child_categories as $child ) : $count++; ?>
                                <article id="" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">

    <div class="entry-thumb">
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $child->cat_ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $child ->cat_name;?>">

    <?php $image_url = z_taxonomy_image_url($child->term_id); ?>
<?php if (!empty($image_url)) : ?>
    <img alt="" src="<?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url($child->term_id);?>" />

<?php else: ?>
    <img alt="" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/blank325_170.png' ) ?>" />

    <?php endif; ?>

        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="entry-detail">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $child->cat_ID ); ?> " rel="bookmark"><?php echo $child ->cat_name;?></a></h2>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-excerpt">
            <?php echo $child ->description;?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->

<?php ?>

                <?php   if ( $count % 2 == 0 ) {
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="row">';
                    }
                    endforeach;
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </main><!-- #main -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Why do you need to count the loop ?

Comment: The "row" div is closed after every second loop and a new div opened.

Comment: Then give the full page code here. It'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I've known `get_template_part()` function does not work with `foreach` loop. So we need to use `locate_template()` function to this case. This is your customized category template code. Put it there -

```
<?php
/**
 * Category Template: Custom
 */

get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="site-content container <?php echo codilight_lite_sidebar_position(); ?>">
        <div class="content-inside">
            <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php 
        $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
        $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
        $child_categories=get_categories(
        array( 
            'parent' => $cat_id,
            // Uncomment the below line if you want empty category to appear on the list. 
            // 'hide_empty'   => 0
            )
        ); 
        if (!empty($child_categories)) : $count = 0; ?>

                    <header class="page-header">
                        <?php
                            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                            the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                        ?>
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->

                    <div class="block1 block1_grid">
                    <?php
                    foreach(array_chunk($child_categories, 2) as $item) {
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                        foreach ($item as $child) {
                            // get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-grid' );
                            include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-grid.php' ) );
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    </div>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </main><!-- #main -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Hope every thing will work perfectly now. :) @jrcollins

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? I'm getting some errors.

Comment: There was a little problem. I missed some `php` tags. Hope now it will be working.

Comment: That's strange, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: What message are you getting ? Can you take an screenshot ? @jrcollins

Comment: There are no error messages. When I check the page using Firebug all the HTML markup is there but it's empty, i.e, no category titles and description. Only the default thumbnail images are showing but the links are broken. It's the same as when I was using the counter.

Comment: @jrcollins, I've edited my code snippet. Now replace your customize archive code. It must gonna work now.  :) :)

Comment: You did it! It works perfectly now. Thank you, I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I just have 1 more problem involving pagination. Maybe you could offer some advice on that? I opened a new thread here: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236899/custom-category-template-pagination-problem).