# Custom category template pagination problem

Tags: categories, pagination

I have customized my theme's category template to display the current category's child categories instead of posts.
Everything is working correctly except for the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function codilight_lite_custom_paginate() in...`

I could remove the function from the template but if possible I would like to keep it so I have the option to paginate the results for categories with a large number of child categories.

Is there any way I can modify the function so it works with the customized template?

Here is the function:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'codilight_lite_custom_paginate' ) ) :
/**
 * Retrieve paginated link for archive post pages.
 */
function codilight_lite_custom_paginate() {
    global $wp_query;
    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $big         = 999999999;
    $translated  = __( 'Page', 'codilight-lite' );

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
        echo '<div class="ft-paginate">';
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'               => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
            'prev_next'          => True,
            'prev_text'          => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            'next_text'          => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            'current'            => $current_page,
            'total'              => $total_pages,
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">'.$translated.' </span>'
        ));
        //echo '<span class="total-pages">Page '. $current_page .' of '. $total_pages .'</span>';
        printf( '<span class="total-pages">'. esc_html__( 'Page %1$s of %2$s', 'codilight-lite' ) .'</span>', $current_page, $total_pages );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
endif;
```

...and here is my customized category template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Category Template: Custom
 */

get_header(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="site-content container <?php echo codilight_lite_sidebar_position(); ?>">
        <div class="content-inside">
            <div id="primary" class="content-area">
                <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
<?php 
        $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
        $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
        $child_categories=get_categories(
        array( 
        'parent' => $cat_id,
        // Uncomment the below line if you want empty category to appear on the list. 
        // 'hide_empty'   => 0
    )
); 
        if (!empty($child_categories)) : $count = 0; ?>

                    <header class="page-header">
                        <?php
                            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                            the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                        ?>
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->

                    <?php
                        echo '<div class="block1 block1_grid">';
                        echo '<div class="row">';

                    foreach ( $child_categories as $child ){ $count++;
                    include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-grid.php' ) );

                    if ( $count % 2 == 0 ) {
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<div class="row">';
                    }
                    }
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                </main><!-- #main -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, modifying this `codilight_lite_custom_paginate()` function is not a good option. Cause if it gets modified then it might cause problem on other pages. So if you want to paginate your `archive.php` child category `foreach` loop then remove the `codilight_lite_custom_paginate()` function and customize your `archive.php` page like below -

```
<?php
/**
 * Category Template: Custom
 */

get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="site-content container <?php echo codilight_lite_sidebar_position(); ?>">
    <div class="content-inside">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <?php
            $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
            $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
            $child_categories=get_categories(
                array(
                    'parent' => $cat_id,
                    // Uncomment the below line if you want empty category to appear on the list.
                    'hide_empty'   => 0
                )
            );

            // Variables for pagination
            $page = isset($_GET['page'])?intval($_GET['page']-1):0;
            $per_page_cat_num = 10;
            $number_of_pages = intval(count($child_categories)/$per_page_cat_num)+1;

            if (!empty($child_categories)) : $count = 0; ?>

                <header class="page-header">
                    <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                    ?>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->
                <?php
                echo '<div class="block1 block1_grid">';
                echo '<div class="row">';

                foreach ( array_slice($child_categories, $page*$per_page_cat_num, $per_page_cat_num) as $child ){
                    $count++;
                    include( locate_template( 'loop-templates/content-grid.php' ) );

                    if ( $count % 2 == 0 ) {
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="row">';
                    }
                }
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- Pagination HTML starts here. Style it how ever you want -->
            <ul id='paginator'>
                <?php
                for( $i=1; $i<$number_of_pages; $i++){?>
                    <li><a href='./?page=<?php echo $i ?>'><?php echo $i ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <!-- Pagination HTML ends here -->

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here `$per_page_cat_num` holds the number of child category you want to show per page. I've assign it default to 10. Change it as your context.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it's not working. I'm testing it on a category with 5 child categories. I set it to show only 3 but it's showing all 5.

Comment: I thought maybe I could create a new function based on the "codight" function so the styles match.

Comment: Styling is not a problem. Just style the pagination as the theme. @jrcollins

Comment: Is pagination not working because I'm listing categories and not posts or because I'm using a custom template?

Comment: Kind of.... Actually the main reason is the, the default pagination is for `WP_Query`. But here we are not using that. So the default pagination will not work here. @jrcollins

Comment: @jrcollins, if this answer satisfied your quest, it would be great for me if you accept the answer.

Comment: Ok, anyway the code you gave me isn't working. It's still listing all the child categories. What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864765/wordpress-get-list-of-child-categories-with-pagination) solution?

Comment: It's another thing. But my code works perfectly I tested it then and also tested it now. If you don't have more than 10 child categories then the pagination will not show. Cause it divides the whole array by 10 and each of them treated as a page. Again I tested it on my machine and it worked pretty well. Using it or not using it, this is your decision. @jrcollins